# Check if string is "null" in C++

Tags: c++, string, null

I know that std::string cannot be null, but I can't figure out the problem here, let me explain. This is my function:

```cpp
void HandleResponse(Mod::PlayerEntry player, std::string response)
```

So `response` usually has a json value, I parse it with nlohmann json:

```cpp
auto value = json::parse(response);
```

In certain occasions, it gives "null", I debugged using:

```cpp
std::cout << "response: " << response << ", value: " << value << std::endl;
// outputs: response: null, value: null
```

Now the problem is that I can't figure out how to compare if it's null, here's all the different checks I've tried:

```cpp
if(response == "null"){}
if(response == ""){}
if(response.empty()){}
if(response == 0){}
if(response == std::string("null")){}
if(response.c_str() == "null"){}
if(response.c_str() == NULL){}
if(response.c_str() == '\0'){}
if(value == "null"){}
```

None of these have worked.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "null".   If you mean a string with length zero, try `if (response.length() == 0)`  or `if (!response.empty())`.

Comment: Can you post a simple example code？

Comment: Please elaborate on "none of these have worked." What happens when you try these checks? What is the code that uses them?

Comment: This is the main variable ```unsigned char **pk```, then these are defined ```auto id = *(unsigned int *) (*pk + 40);
    auto data = *(std::string *) (*pk + 48);```, the `data` variable is passed to `HandleResponse` as `response`.

Comment: What is the type of `response`? Does the json library not allow you to check if the value is null? Looking at `nlohmann` it looks like `json::parse()` returns an object of `json`. Note this is not a `std::string`. The `json` object has a convenient type checker: `value.is_null()`.

Comment: Note: `null` is a valid json response. https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @xBeastMode -  If you're doing those things you describe in your comment, you definitely haven't provided enough information.    The value that `pk` takes is critical to how your code works, and your question includes no such information.     Using that sort of pointer trickery could also well mean you are in the realms of undefined behaviour.      Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: Actually, it's been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604886/9922018

Comment: Maybe so.   But not because you provided any useful information here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that response can potentially contain white space. So comparing it exactly for null might be harder than you think. You need to check if `response` contains `null` but that anything else is simple white space.

But looking at `nlohmann` library the `json::parse()` function returns an object of type `json`.

```
json value = json::parse(response);
```

You can simply check the type of the value:

```
id (value.is_null())    {std::cout << "is null\n";}
id (value.is_boolean()) {std::cout << "is bool\n";}
id (value.is_number())  {std::cout << "is numb\n";}
id (value.is_object())  {std::cout << "is obj\n";}
id (value.is_array())   {std::cout << "is array\n";}
id (value.is_string())  {std::cout << "is string\n";}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. It's also described in the library's [readme](https://github.com/nlohmann/json?tab=readme-ov-file#stl-like-access) in its Github repo and the [doc](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/is_null/#nlohmannbasic_jsonis_null). Also the tip that the response might contain white space is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If `response` is a `std::string`, and inserting it into an output stream produces "null", then a correct way to compare it is `response == "null"`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the cause is really stupid. I trimmed the string with:

```cpp
boost::trim(response);
```

Now I checked if the response is "null":

```cpp
if (response == "null") return;
```

and boom, it works!